# div video resize dynamic

Tags: css, video, html, resize

I have a div box on the right of my screen with a width of 40%

when I embed a youtube video in there it sticks out the side

I know you can manually change the dimensions of the video in pixel size, but is there not a way you can make it so that the video will resize automatically to fit in snugly?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [FitVids](http://fitvidsjs.com/), which is a jQuery plugin for fluid width video embeds.